# DENSE_RANK() Query

Tags: sql, t-sql, dense-rank

I have something similar to the below dataset...

```
ID        RowNumber
101       1
101       2
101       3
101       4
101       5
101       1
101       2
```

What I would like to get is an additional column as below...

```
ID        RowNumber        New
101       1                1
101       2                1
101       3                1
101       4                1
101       5                1
101       1                2
101       2                2
```

I have toyed with dense_rank(), but no such luck.

Comment: You need a column that specifies the ordering of the rows.

Comment: What are the ***rules*** that determine your output to be the needed output from the given input ?  Format the answer as "for each row of the input, I want to compute the value for New as ......".

Answer (score 1):

Gordon already mentioned, you required a column to specify the order of data. If i consider ID as order by column, this following logic may help you to get your desired result-

```
WITH your_table(ID,RowNumber)
AS
(
SELECT 101,1 UNION ALL
SELECT 101,2 UNION ALL
SELECT 101,3 UNION ALL
SELECT 101,4 UNION ALL
SELECT 101,5 UNION ALL
SELECT 101,1 UNION ALL
SELECT 101,2
)

SELECT A.ID,A.RowNumber,
SUM(RN) OVER 
(
    ORDER BY ID
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED  PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
) +1 New
FROM
(
    SELECT *, 
    CASE 
        WHEN LAG(RowNumber) OVER(ORDER BY ID) > RowNumber THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END RN
    FROM your_table
)A
```

Above will always change the ROW NUMBER if the value in RowNumber decreased than previous one. Alternatively, the same output alsoo can be achieved if you wants to change row number whenever value 1 found. This is bit static option-

```
SELECT A.ID,A.RowNumber,
SUM(RN) OVER 
(
    ORDER BY ID
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED  PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
)  New
FROM(
    SELECT *, 
    CASE 
        WHEN RowNumber = 1 THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END RN
    FROM your_table
)A
```

Output is-

```
ID  RowNumber   New
101 1           1
101 2           1
101 3           1
101 4           1
101 5           1
101 1           2
101 2           2
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering unless a column specifies the ordering.

Assuming you have such a column, you can do what you want simply by counting the number of "1" up to each point:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when rownumber = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id order by <ordering column>) as new
from t;
```

Comment: His example table isn't even a set.

Comment: Since duplicate values are allowed, SQL tables represent *unordered **multi-sets***.

Answer (score 0):

As Gordon alluded to, there is no default order in your example so it's difficult to imagine how to get a deterministic result (e.g. where the same values supplied to the same query always resulting in the exact same answer.)

This sample data includes a sequential PK column which is used to *define the order of this set*.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (PK INT IDENTITY, ID INT, RowNumber INT)
INSERT @tbl(ID, RowNumber) VALUES (101,1),(101,2),(101,3),(101,4),(101,5),(101,1),(101,2);

SELECT t.* FROM @tbl AS t;
```

**Returns:**

```
PK    ID     RowNumber
----- ------ -----------
1     101    1
2     101    2
3     101    3
4     101    4
5     101    5
6     101    1
7     101    2
```

This query uses DENSE_RANK to get you what you want:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (PK INT IDENTITY, ID INT, RowNumber INT)
INSERT @tbl(ID, RowNumber) VALUES (101,1),(101,2),(101,3),(101,4),(101,5),(101,1),(101,2);

SELECT t.ID, t.RowNumber, New = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY t.PK - RowNumber)
FROM @tbl AS t;
```

**Returns:**

```
ID    RowNumber   New
----- ----------- ------
101   1           1
101   2           1
101   3           1
101   4           1
101   5           1
101   1           2
101   2           2
```

Note that ORDER BY New does not affect the plan.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below
Load the data into Temp table

Select id,RowNumber,Row_number()over(partition by RowNumber Order by id)New from #temp
Order by Row_number()over(partition by RowNumber Order by id),RowNumber